# How to access common memory location via multiple VCs ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I am creating an iOS app that uses core data in almost every VC.

The app has many Navigation Controller and different types of segues.

I want all these viewControllers to be using the same Managed object context. Also, I do not want to keep using prepare to segue to do this as I can use that to pass more relevant info for a particular VC.

Hence, I need help to create a central class or something similar that will help me get the same instance of the managed object context in all my VCs.

Comment: Try singleton. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598820/correct-singleton-pattern-objective-c-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Singleton Pattern](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/)!

```
@class SingleTonnedClass;
@interface SingleTonnedClass : NSObject
   + (SingleTonnedClass*)sharedInstance;
   - (id)getterInstanceMethod;
   .
   .
   .
@end
```

In .m

```
@implementation SingleTonnedClass
  SingleTonnedClass *singleTonInstance;
  + (SingleTonnedClass*)sharedInstance
    {
       if(!singleTonInstance)
       {
         singleTonInstance = [SingleTonnedClass new];
       }
    }

  ...
  .
  .
  other method implementation
@end
```

From anywhere in your project you can access the instance of SingleTon class by just including its header and,

```
  [SingleTonnedClass shatedInstance]; //will return you the singleton instance
```

and access methods like this

```
 [[SingleTonnedClass sharedInstance]someMethod];
```