# Allocating and initialize class one time and use it

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom `NSObject` class, with my array in for my data which I want to use etc. But how can I alloc and init this class object, and use it everywhere without always using: `CustomClass class = [[CustomClass alloc] init];` because this makes an object every time from my class, so the data is totally off.

I am always getting things about how to `alloc/init` something but nothing about on how to handle a class that says in the memory and you can use each time without making a new one trough all your other classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read up about *singletons* or *shared instances*. Here is the currently most agreed upon version:

```
+ (MyClass *)sharedInstance {

    static MyClass *sharedInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken,^{

        sharedInstance=[[MyClass alloc]init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Now `MyClass.sharedInstance` (or `[MyClass sharedInstance]` for old syntax) will give you a single shared instance of your class. The `dispatch_once` stuff is to make it thread safe. Obviously you need to replace `MyClass` with the name of your class.

Comment: Many peoply prefer to use the "dot syntax" only for *properties* (but there are different opinions), but I would not call `[MyClass sharedInstance]` the "old syntax".

Comment: Yeah, obviously that I need to change the name of "MyClass" haha, thanks for the information! Going to read up a bit more about those things!

Comment: @Martin R: true. But it is less typing and faster to read, so I have been using it more and more for cases like that as well. Though I do not have a strong preference either way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Singleton pattern as explained in this answer [Correct Singleton Pattern Objective C (iOS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598820/correct-singleton-pattern-objective-c-ios?rq=1) 
Only one instance of the class runs and can be used throughout your code.

Comment: That code is significantly outdated and should not be copied. Gerd's code works absolutely fine and reliably. And doesn't work with ARC, which is what everyone is using nowadays.